# File IO Close() method error in ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am doing a simple file IO in MVC6. I have added `System.IO` NuGet package. However, it gives me compile time error. VS IDE doesn't show any red mark when I type the code. The `Close()` method also appears in intellisense. Please help!

## My Code

```
StreamWriter writer = System.IO.File.CreateText("some_valid_path");
writer.WriteLine("test");
writer.Close();
```

## Error

> **StreamWriter does not contain a definition for 'Close' and no extension method 'Close'** accepting a first argument of type 'StreamWriter' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thank you.

Comment: Try to use Dispose instead of Close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you use the core CLR? The `StreamWriter.Close` method are not available in core CLR. You can use `Dispose` method replace.
You also can use `using` statement:

```
using (var writer = System.IO.File.CreateText("your_path"))
{
    writer.WriteLine("text");
}
```